# Adding images to top of each column for each group on a chart

Tags: highcharts

I plan to use scatter series to add markers (image) above each bar of a highcharts chart. On the jsFiddle example, I would like for example that the sun to be placed above the blue columns, the cloud on the gray and again a sun on the green ones. It's simple when there is a series (http://jsfiddle.net/yucca/tffevbrf/), but when there are several I can not do it. Can you help me ?

http://jsfiddle.net/yucca/2rt10hje/1/

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
  type: 'column'
},
xAxis: {
  categories: true
},

series: [{
    name: 'Serie1',
    data: [2.7,4.7]
    }, {
    name: 'serie2',
    data: [16.0,20.2]
    }, {
    name: 'serie3',
    data: [8.8,7.4]
      }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [25,25],
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    marker: { symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)' }
    }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [10,10],
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    marker: { symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)' }
    },{
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [5,5],
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    showInLegend: false,
    marker: { symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)' }
    }, 
  ],



});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't work because you have incorrect definition of series there:

```
data: [
        //{ y: 30, marker: { symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)' }},
        {
        data: [10,10],
        marker: { symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)' }
        }, {
        data: [10,10],
        marker: { symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)' }
        }, 
      ],
```

There you can see the data objects inside of data array, what is not supported by API. However, it's not all.

To achieve the effect that you expecting you need to add exactly six points (three for each of category). Remember, that categories are also the `xAxis` values, so you can assign decimal values as an `x` value, just like that:
data: [

```
// First category
{
  x: -0.20,
  y: 25,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
  }
}, {
  x: 0,
  y: 25,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }
}, {
  x: 0.20,
  y: 25,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
  }
}, 
// Second category
{
  x: 0.80,
  y: 25,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
  }
}, {
  x: 1,
  y: 25,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
  }
}, {
  x: 1.20,
  y: 25,
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
  }
}]
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9up6oo3n/